# For loop testing in Salesforce

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, loop

I am attempting to write a simple test for a for loop that cleans the websites fields of unwanted elements such as 'http', 'www' etc. The script works for me but the test class that I wrote gets me 0% of coverage. Could anyone advise on what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

So here's the actual script:

```
public class standardiseWebsites {
list<Account> accts = [SELECT Website FROM Account];
public standardiseWebsites(){

    for (Account acct : accts){
        string website = acct.website; 
        website = website.replace('http://www.','');
        website = website.replace('https://www.','');
        website = website.replace('https://','');
        website = website.replace('http://','');
        website = website.replace('www.','');
        acct.website = website;
        update acct;

    }
}
```

And here's the test:

```
@isTest
public class standardiseWebsitesTest {
static testMethod void standardiseWebsitesTest(){
    //Create test Accounts with various types of websites

    Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Website='https://www.test.com');
    insert account1;
    Account account2 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Website='http://www.test.com');
    insert account2;
    Account account3 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Website='https://test.com');
    insert account3;                                      
    Account account4 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Website='http://test.com');
    insert account4;
    Account account5 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Website='www.test.com');                                                           
    insert account5;
    Account account6 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Website='test.com');                                                           
    insert account6;

    Test.startTest();

    System.debug(accts);
    StandardiseWebsitesTest obj = new standardiseWebsitesTest();

    Test.stopTest();

    //Check the desired results
    system.assertEquals(Account1.Website,'test.com');
    system.assertEquals(Account2.Website,'test.com');            
    system.assertEquals(Account3.Website,'test.com');            
    system.assertEquals(Account4.Website,'test.com');
    system.assertEquals(Account5.Website,'test.com');            
    system.assertEquals(Account6.Website,'test.com');        



}
```

Comment: Is your `standardiseWebsites` class even compiling? I'm fairly certain that DML is not allowed in class constructors.

Comment: @DerekF It's not a best practice, but you can put a DML in a constructor. However, you get a runtime exception if you use that constructor in a Visualforce page.

Answer (score 4):

**Your unit test is failing because you forgot to query the records back afterwards.**

Make sure you query the records back after calling your method.

**Your script won't work if any accounts have a null website value.**

Make sure you restrict your query to just accounts that have a website.

**Your script logic might remove important URL information.**

Imagine you have the URL to a page in the Wayback Machine:

> https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.google.com/.

Guess what? You broke it. Instead, just parse the details you want:

```
Url u = new Url(acct.Website);
acct.Website = u.getHost()+u.getPath();
```

A word of advice: do not remove the "www." Many websites will not work correctly if you remove it. While major sites like Google and Yahoo don't need it, there are many small websites that do. This all depends on the DNS configuration for the website.

Answer (score 0):

DML and webservice call is not allowed inside the constructor. Not sure how you did that.